# Steps in calculating yaw, pitch, and roll (Space Modeling)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

I have a golf club that has four markers on its face and a device which outputs their fiducials data (xyz locations with the ball being the center) through out a swing until the impact. The device automatically calibrates the markers in terms of the ball instead of the camera device.

I have constructed a coordinate system using the markers data to calculate yaw, pitch, roll, and I'm applying (R.from_matrix(frame_orientation[i])) where R is (from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R), and the variable frame orientation[i] represents the vectors of the CS at time i.

At this point, I'm missing a huge step or making a mistake somewhere because the output euler angles do not make sense.

Just to summarize what I have done,

The four markers consist of (TopToe, MidToe, BotToe, Midheel) and I get a midpoint by doing ((MidToe + Midheel) / 2) and construct the coordinate system with the origin being the center point.

Then I have vectors that represent the CS at frame t and I use them as the input for outputting euler angles.....

Do I need to transform the cs vectors further? Thank you for any advices or help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfEmG.jpg)

Where I'm constructing the CS:

xyz_frames = []

for i in range(len(mtoe_txyz[:,0]))[:37]:
y_axis = x1[i] / np.linalg.norm(x1[i], ord=2)

```
x_axis = np.cross(x1[i], x2[i])


z_axis = np.cross(x_axis, x1[i])

x_axis = x_axis / np.linalg.norm(x_axis, ord=2)
z_axis = z_axis /  np.linalg.norm(z_axis, ord=2)
xyz_frames.append(np.array([x_axis, y_axis, z_axis, center_point[i, 1:4]]))
```

Setting up the frames and applying the vectors to Euler angles function:

frame_orientation = []

for i in range(len(xyz_frames)):
xyz_frame = xyz_frames[i][0:3:]
frame_orientation.append(np.transpose(xyz_frame))

ypr = []

for i in range(len(frame_orientation)):
r = R.from_matrix(frame_orientation[i])

```
ypr.append(r.as_euler('zyx', degrees=True))
```

Comment: Random guess: are you sure you want your axes orientation relative to the markers? Pitch is usually measured with reference to flat ground (for example)

Comment: @BarryCarter My goal is to figure out the rotation of the club, specifically its club face. Would it need to be relative to the ball instead of having the cs's origin as the center point of the club face?

Comment: I probably misunderstood and thought you were using direction of travel as one of your coordinate system axes, in which case the pitch would always be 0. Could you show us your code and what weird answers you're getting?

Comment: @BarryCarter That's a good idea, I'll add the codes to the post

Comment: There is [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange

Comment: @TymaGaidash I think they require that works and does what it's supposed to do.